# pulseaudio.service "Failed to start Sound Service."

Tags: pulseaudio, manjaro, journalctl

On my desktop I get multiple errors regarding `pulseaudio` in `journalctl` after bootup:

```
Jun 10 15:50:51 Workstation systemd[1146]: Failed to start Sound Service.                                                                                                                                           
Jun 10 15:50:51 Workstation systemd[1146]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 10 15:50:51 Workstation systemd[1146]: pulseaudio.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 10 15:50:51 Workstation systemd[1146]: Stopped Sound Service.
Jun 10 15:50:51 Workstation systemd[1146]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 10 15:50:51 Workstation systemd[1146]: pulseaudio.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: Failed to start Sound Service.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation pulseaudio[1413]: E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation pulseaudio[1413]: E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation rtkit-daemon[1244]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation rtkit-daemon[1244]: Successfully made thread 1413 of process 1413 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: Starting Sound Service...
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: Stopped Sound Service.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: pulseaudio.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: Failed to start Sound Service.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation pulseaudio[1407]: E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation pulseaudio[1407]: E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation rtkit-daemon[1244]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation rtkit-daemon[1244]: Successfully made thread 1407 of process 1407 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: Starting Sound Service...
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: Stopped Sound Service.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: pulseaudio.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: Failed to start Sound Service.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation pulseaudio[1396]: E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation pulseaudio[1396]: E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation rtkit-daemon[1244]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation rtkit-daemon[1244]: Successfully made thread 1396 of process 1396 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: Starting Sound Service...
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: Stopped Sound Service.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Jun 10 15:50:50 Workstation systemd[1146]: pulseaudio.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 10 15:50:49 Workstation systemd[1146]: Failed to start Sound Service.
Jun 10 15:50:49 Workstation systemd[1146]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 10 15:50:49 Workstation systemd[1146]: pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 10 15:50:49 Workstation pulseaudio[1376]: E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
Jun 10 15:50:49 Workstation pulseaudio[1376]: E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
```

Why do these issues appear?
Is this something to worry about?

I did not notice this before, because sound is playing and volume icons also work.

I am running Manjaro (`4.17.0-2-MANJARO`) with `i3wm` and `pulseaudio 11.1`.

Comment: downgrade pulseaudio solved the issue (in my case)